# React: use or not to use Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I've looked for Immutable.js motivation when using React.js. As I understand React.js should guarantee immutability of properties. But, I can change view properties [in this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/16597/):

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var item = { prop: 128 };
        return <Test item={item} />;
    }
});

var Test = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        this.props.item = -2; // Don't throw any error
        return <div>{this.props.item}</div>; // Returns -2 instead of object
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

---

**Update:** thanks to @FelixKling, now I know that properties will be immutable since React v0.14 (which is comming soon).

**Question:** What's the motivation to use `Immutable.js` with `React v0.14`?

---

**Update2:** Can we really change parent's properties? in SubComponent

```
let somePropVal = { a: 1 };
<SubComponent someProp={somePropVal} />
//....Then in SubComponent
this.props.someProp.a = 2; // somePropVal.a still will be `1` at parent element
```

Comment: AFAIK props are only "immutable" (the object is actually *frozen*) in v0.14. The demo uses v0.13. *edit:* Yep: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/09/10/react-v0.14-rc1.html#breaking-changes

Comment: @FelixKling what's the motivation of using `Immutable.js` in v0.14 than?

Comment: @limelights yeah, but if I can stay with habitual js API, and there is no more reasons to switch - I won't use `Immutable.js`

Comment: You would use Immutable.js if you want the values themselves to be immutable, e.g. if you pass a complex data structure as prop and that structure should be immutable.

Comment: @FelixKling good catch! That's sounds strange for me that React guys freeze only props references without their internals

Comment: The difference is that React itself creates and controls the `props` object. But silently freezing user provided data (i.e. the prop values) could easily break the user's code.

Comment: @FelixKling look at update2 section pls. Isn't it enough to ensure store's state immutability?

Comment: Have you tried it? Props (and objects in general) are not cloned / copied when passed.

Comment: @V_B I used Immutable.js when I first started learning React because it forces you to think more about data and state changes. As I've gotten more familiar with where to do different things within my React apps I've generally not used Immutable.js anymore because I've become much better at minimizing state changes. That being said, in addition to the optimizations you gain from it, you can get ever further optimizations if you mix Immutable.js with the PureRenderMixin

Comment: @MatthewHerbst yeah, that's look the main argument to use `Immutable.js` - deep equals for data structures. But it seems strange to add `Immutable.js` for equals purposes. Maybe there is more lightweight solution?

Comment: @V_B all Immutable is really doing is writing code that you could write on your own - it just has a library that makes it very easy. You can easily write "immutable" code on your own - just is a bit harder.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I'm developing SPA for mobile, so memory usage is critical for me. Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't want do add  a big library with persistent data structures (which takes more memory for data storage) just to check if two objects are equal

Comment: @V_B Immutable, or any library, isn't necessarily going to eat up memory - it will just mean a minuscule larger download for the install files. Using a well developed library such as Immutable is likely going to save memory compared to doing it on your own. Note that `immutable != persistent`. Immutable simply means that you can't modify an object after creating it - though you can very efficiently create a new, modified object based on the contents of the previous object, which can then be destroyed.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst yeap, but the reason why I'm so carefully treat `Immutable.js` is that it may be slower on not tremendously huge amounts of data. There are many tests, some of them adore `Immutable.js` some are not. Here one of them http://jsperf.com/plain-js-vs-immutable-vs-mori/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After facing all rakes with react pure rendering I want to say that `Immutable.js` **is not about providing deepEqual method. The main point is to clone state on each modification.**

*Why you need to clone state on each modification?*

Everything goes well till view's state consists of primitive values only. But one moment that may happen it be an array or complex object tree.

Suppose you have a view `YourView` which takes an array from a store `YourStore`. and you don't want to use `Immutable.js`, just include Node.LS's `deepEqual`. For instance:

***`PureRenderMixin.js`***

```
const deepEqual = require('deep-equal');

module.exports = function pureRenderMixin(Component) {
    Component.prototype.shouldComponentUpdate = function(nextProps, nextState) {
        return !deepEqual(this.props, nextProps) || !deepEqual(this.state, nextState);
    };
    return Component;
};
```

***`YourView.react.js`***

```
class YourView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);
        this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        YourStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    }

    _onChange() {            
        this.setState({array: YourStore.getArray()});
    }
}

module.exports = PureRenderMixin(YourView);
```

***`YourStore.js`***

```
......
getArray() { return _array; }

switch(action.type) {
   case ActionTypes.UPDATE_USER_FLAG:
       _array[action.index].value= action.flag; // BUG!!!
       YourStore.emitChange();
       break;
}
```

**Problem #1: shouldComponentUpdate return false instead of true** you expect that `_array[action.index].value = action.flag;` will update `YourView`, but it doesn't. It doesn't because `shouldComponentUpdate` will return `false`.

The reason is that array is just a reference, and at the moment of `this.setState({array: YourStore.getArray()})` this.state.array (previous state) is also updated. That means that inside `shouldComponentUpdate` method `this.state` & `nextState` refs will point to the same object.

**Problem 1# solution:**

You need to copy array reference before update it (i.e. with help of lodash):

***`YourStore.js`***

```
......
getArray() { return _array; }

switch(action.type) {
   case ActionTypes.UPDATE_USER_FLAG:
       _array = _.cloneDeep(_array); // FIXED, now the previous state will differ from the new one
       _array[action.index].value= action.flag; // BUG!!!
       YourStore.emitChange();
       break;
}
```

**Problem #2:  sometimes you need to clone _array multiple times, code get buggy**

Suppose you need to update multiple values of `_array` inside `if` statements:

```
   case ActionTypes.UPDATE_USER_FLAG:
       // You can't clone the _array once, because you don't know which conditions will be executed
       // Also conditions may not be executed at all, so you can't clone the _array outside of if statements
       if (someCondition) {
           _array = _.cloneDeep(_array);
           _array[someIndex].value= action.flag;
       }
       if (anotherCondition) {
           _array = _.cloneDeep(_array);
           _array[anotherIndex].value= action.flag;
       }
       YourStore.emitChange();
       break;
```

**Problem #2 solution:** use `Immutable.js`. Benefits:

1. It has clear interface and makes it clear for your colleges that the state should be cloned each time
2. It has batch updates, so you shouldn't worry about cloning array multiple times

Answer (score 2):

immutable.js boost react perfomance with PureRenderMixin

Source of PureRenderMixin:

```
var ReactComponentWithPureRenderMixin = {
  shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    return !shallowEqual(this.props, nextProps) ||
           !shallowEqual(this.state, nextState);
  }
};
```

With immutable.js compare two objects in shallowEqual are very fast